# Is it possible to restore a Windows 7 installation from a Windows backup?

Tags: windows, installation, backup, partitioning, restore

I bought an HP laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium preinstalled. It has a label with Windows serial number. However a Windows Installation DVD was not provided. I want to repartition the HDD to install Ubuntu and create a data partition. But I want to be sure that I will be able to restore Windows even if I reformat hdd or replace it by another one.

Is it enough to burn the system image on a bunch of DVD+Rdl and System repair disc using Windows 7 standard tools and save them in a safe place?

By standard tools I mean:

- "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore -> Create a system image" and
- "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore -> Create a system repair disc"

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP has a utility to make HP Recovery Media

I suggest you make this media before making any partition changes. Use good quality DVD+R media. These discs will allow you to return the system to "as shipped" condition.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867124

Also make the "System Repair Disc" you mentioned, I doubt you will ever need it but if you do there is no substitute.

If you want to capture a hard drive snapshot of how it is currently, [I suggest Easeus Todo backup Free](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/free-backup-software.htm), use this to make a full disk image of the hard drive. This software is much more flexible than the Windows disk image software.

[It is also recommended to read this tutorial](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-loaded-Windows-7/m-p/742019) on how to create a 5th partition without damaging the Windows installation on a HP notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make the HP Recovery Media like described bye Moab. Additional create a backup of your data.

That said it is **not** needed to reinstall Windows after installing Linux. Most Linux distributions are able to shrink your windows partition without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Windows system repair disc cannot re-install your Windows after formatting your hard drives, the best solution I can see here is backup your data, as you told you are having a serial key so you can download an original copy from Microsoft website, burn it on a DVD, re-partition you hard disk, now you install Ubuntu and Windows. Now restore your backup data from your backup file.

Comment: He can't install Windows. He didn't get a Windows disc with his PC, as he explained. If he wanted to buy a second Windows license he wouldn't have bothered posting this question.

Comment: @_CarlF That's why I told him to download an .iso image on wWondows 7 OS and burn it on a disc, no need to buy another license for that :)

Comment: No, but I believe it's illegal, and if he has an OEM license I'm pretty sure it won't activate generic Windows (although I could be wrong).